# Light path in a Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics

This might be a silly question for the physicist as I'm not one but I've have watched this YouTube [**video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjWjZFwz3rQ&t=323s) which shows the steps needed to simulate light path in a Schwarzschild spacetime, what I failed to get is how he (the uploader of the video) jumped from these two following equations:

1. Schwarzschild metric

$$\left(1 - \frac{R_\text s}{r}\right) c^2 dt^2 -\frac{1}{1 - \frac{R_\text s}{r}} dr^2 - r^2 d\theta^2 - r^2 \sin^2\theta d\phi^2 = 0$$

2. Geodesic equation

$$\frac{d^2 x^{\alpha}}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu v} \frac{dx^\mu}{ds} \frac{dx^v}{ds} = 0$$

to the following second order differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\phi^2} = \frac{3}{2} R_\text s u^2 - u$$
$$u = \frac{1}{r}$$

Can anyone show the steps or link a url where these steps are discussed in detail?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematics.  It's the site standard.  Using images is really frowned upon and actively discouraged.

Comment: This is a fairly big topic. To get some of the underlying theory, you could look at sections 5.6 and 5.7 of my GR book, which is free online: http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/